# I understand bootstrap code, but I don't know how to use in rails in critical part

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a new learner and I am confused using bootstrap code in rails, here is the example of the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "MARKET", root_path, class: "navbar-brand",id: "logo"%>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "create doc", new_detail_path%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Signout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
          else
            <li><%= link_to "login", new_user_session_path%></li>
            <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I know the user part ul is wrong, I don't know how to use bootstrap in rails.
Is there any tutorial to learn bootstrap with rails because I am really confused to use bootstrap in rails.

Comment: Why do you think user ul is wrong? Also, bootstrap is just a bunch of css and js. You use it exactly like you would use any other css and js.

Comment: No it is not wrong but I do not know how to do the code properly, when I checked the navigation, it is not in a proper order, the create doc, signout, and login is not in a proper order at the navigation

Comment: sooo, shuffle them around and see if it produces desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here the article how to integrate bootstrap in rails app:
https://launchschool.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1